# Cobertura, how to coverage catch-clause which will never occur

Tags: cobertura

i have the ambitious goal to get 100% test coverage in cobertura. How can i achieve this on this code? There will never be an exception because the file is on the classpath. Can i remove files fropm classpath with junit?

```
    try {
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(WsdlSource.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("stringresources/stringresources.properties"), "UTF-8");
        try {
            p.load(reader);
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Could you please post more code? The `p` object is an instance of some class, does this class implements an interface? Such cases can be resolved with Mock Objects but you have to write your code so that it is testable. For example creating instances with `new` operator is not a good idea if you want your code to be testable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to be able to test things right you have to learn what what [loose coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) is and what [Mock Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) are.

Basically, it is never a good idea to create an object with `new` because you create a hard dependency between the class `InputStreamReader` and your logic.

If your object `p` implements some kind of an interface, it would be good if you pass the instance of it from outside of your logic. Some implementations of Mock Objects also allow you to mock a class but I would not recommend that.

For example if you write your code like that:

```
public myMethod(SomeKindOfInterface p, InputStreamReader reader) {
    try {
        p.load(reader);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
          reader.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
          //intentionally left blank, nothing could be done upon exception on closing
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your JUnit you could use [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) to mock the `IOException`.

```
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(WsdlSource.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("stringresources/stringresources.properties"), "UTF-8");
SomeKindOfInterface mock = Mockito.mock(SomeKindOfInterface.class);
Mockito.when(mock.load(reader)).thenThrow(new IOException());
myInstance.myMethod(mock, reader);
```

This way you would have your `catch` block covered.